# How do I get related model from collection in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have a method returning all job post data. This is what I have tried:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $applicantData = Applicant::whereId($id)->first();
    $jobData = Job::all();
    //dd($jobData);
    //dd($jobData->job_title);
    return view('applicant.confirmation',compact("applicantData","jobData"));
}
```

`dd($jobData);` [returns](http://prnt.sc/dw6ctp):

[image: image of jobData]

`dd($jobData->job_title);` it returns an error:

> ErrorException in ApplicantController.php line 150: Undefined
>   property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$job_title

How can I get the `$jobData->job_title` value?

Comment: `$jobData->first()->job_title` for first jobs title. Collection is like an array. it contains all the items.

Comment: @CerlinBoss Its returns every time first `job_title`.If i change `job_id` into something else but it always kepp first `job_title`.

Comment: show me your jobdata table structure

Comment: @msonowal Applicants table http://prnt.sc/dw6r9k and jobs table http://prnt.sc/dw6rec

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud :  Read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections) and use which ever method which make sense

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud If you want a specific record, why won't you query for it like, `$job = Job::find($id);` and access it like `$job->job_title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function show($id)
{
    $applicantData = Applicant::whereId($id)->first();
    $jobData = Job::find($applicantData->job_id); //this will give you the job
    dd($jobData);
    dd($jobData->job_title);
    return view('applicant.confirmation',compact("applicantData","jobData"));
}
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for.Thanks Accepted.. : )

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate collections using the `each` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#collection-method) in Laravel:

```
$jobData->each(function ($item, $key) {
  dd($item->job_title);
});
```

Comment: I want to show `job_title` which is already their in database.But its returns all `job_title`.I want specific one.Could you tell me ? If i change job_id into anything `job_title` all time returns "Admin Assistant" in your way

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud, if you want to fetch specific `Job` item, then you probably shouldn't fetch all items with `Job::all()`, but use the appropriate method that returns a single `Job` instance. For example, you can use the [get](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_get) method. If you still need all the job items, but need to perform some action depending on a `Job` property, then add a check into the loop like `if ($item->job_id == 12345) { ... }`. So it is unclear what you mean by "specific one".

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through `$jobData` since it will return all rows. Something like:

```
$jobData = Job::all();
foreach ($jobData as $job) {
    echo $job->job_title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are object in arrays so you can directly pickout the value. If you need first item then `$jobData[0]->job_title` or `$jobData->first()->job_title` or you can loop `foreach($jobData as $data){$data->job_title}`

Answer (score 1):

`$jobData` is a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections) so you cannot directly access `job_title` like `$jobData->job_title`. I figure you want to access them in your view file. hence do following

```
@foreach($jobData as $job)
    {{ $job->job_title }}
@endforeach
```